# Jquery only droppable if list length is less than 4?

Tags: jquery, list, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

This code will run but it won't stop accepting new items when the lists length becomes 3 or greater. Essentially it's a card pile and when it has 3 cards dropped in it I'd like it to stop accepting cards and if you take one out I'd like it to accept again until it reaches 3. I'm guessing the list length is not being rechecked. Any way around this or alternative solutions would be fantastic

```
        // let the very important be droppable but accept a max of 3 cards, accepting the gallery items

       $vi.droppable({
      if ($(vi).length < 3) {
      acceptg: "#gallery li",
        accepti: "#i li",
        acceptni: "#ni li",      
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
        deleteImage( ui.draggable ) 
        else {
        $(vi).droppable( "option", "disabled", true );



         }  
        }
        });
```

Comment: you should check the amount of items after the drop and then disable or re-enable droppable depending on it: `$vi.droppable('disable')` and `$vi.droppable("enable");` - [more info](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

Comment: @Pete Is it not `$vi.droppable( "option", "disabled", true );` ?

Comment: @Pete @singe31 Thanks a million. I attempted it but I can't get it to work, is this what you meant? 

`if ( $('#vi li').length < 4 )
{
   $vi.droppable({
      acceptg: "#gallery li",
      accepti: "#i li",
      acceptni: "#ni li",      
      activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        deleteImage( ui.draggable )
            if ( $('#vi li').length > 3 )
             { 
               vi.droppable( "option", "disabled", true );
             }else{ 
             vi.droppable( "option", "disabled", false ); }

 }
   })
}; 
`

Comment: @singe31 according to the api you can use both ways. Genesis are you just dragging and dropping between two lists?  If so you may be better off using sortable instead: http://jsfiddle.net/PTDGv/1/, if not you need to do your ifs within the drop function - of droppable

Comment: @Pete It's a group of draggable cards and sorting them into 3 droppable piles. I've updated the code above. I'm new to coding so I'm probably missing something very basic